# How to load Python 3 Pickled SKlearn Model in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pickle, python-3.6

I have a Python 3.6 script that trains an SKLearn model and then saves the model using the following code:

```
with open('filepath', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(trained_model, f, protocol=2)
```

When I try to load the pickle in python 3.6, things work out just fine:

```
>>with open('filepath', 'rb') as f:
>>    model = pickle.load(f)
>>
>>model

RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
        max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
        min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
        min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=80, n_jobs=1,
        oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
        warm_start=False)
```

when I run this same pickle.load command in Python 2.7, I get the following error:

```
>>with open('filepath', 'rb') as f:
>>    model = pickle.load(f)

ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling
```

Looking at documentation and similar cases, setting protocol to 2 *should* make the pickle file compatible. What is causing this issue and how can I work around it?

Comment: Is that the full traceback?

Comment: unfortunately, it is.

Comment: I cannot say anything else at this point 'cuz you didn't provide any [mcve] for me to diagnose.

Comment: see update, this might help you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pickle._load()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/99d208efed97e02d813e8166925b998bbd0d3993/Lib/pickle.py#L1747) instead of `.load()` to [force using a pure-Python implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pickle.py#L1568) and get a more useful traceback.

If the faulty part is in `numpy`'s code though, you're still left to using a C debugger or tracing the source code by hand...
*...Or using [`numpy` pickle format spec](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/neps/npy-format.html)* on the part that is fed to `numpy`'s unpickling routine and try to guess what is wrong with it!

- **[`pickletools.dis()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickletools.html?highlight=pickletools#pickletools.dis) does this for you! It prints a disassembly of pickle data, complete with offsets.** Though you might still need the spec to find out the nature of the violation.

That said, [3.4. Model persistence — scikit-learn 0.19.1 documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) does warn that loading model data in another version and/or architecture is not supported and suggests saving source material instead.

Comment: the links to _load() and 'force using a pure python..' seem to be pointing to the wrong lines. Permalinks should be used instead